# Are there any practical solutions to allow carrying dog bags on Shabbas?

Tags: shabbat, animals

If someone lives in a small community without an eruv and would like to walk his dog (for his benefit and health) on Shabbas.

In most locations people are required to pick up and dispose of dog leavings and can be fined if they don't. On a week day a person would normally carry dog bags, possibly in a small pouch attached to his lead.

On Shabbas a person can't carry the bags and presumably can't have the dog carry them either (by attaching them to his lead).

There is also the associated problem with using and then disposing of a bag when it is used.

Are there any practical solutions to these problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you live in a home with a fenced in yard, your yard is permissible (since it is enclosed private property) and you can use the doggy bag in the yard. If there is an apartment building that has an eruv that includes a yard, it would also be a possibility. That would seem to be the easiest solution to your problem. Otherwise, the apartment building yard is the same problem as walking outside with no eruv.

If the dog can be trained to only go in some other private yard (and not on the way to the yard) that might be a possible solution. Similarly if several Jews can connect their yards with an eruv, that might also be a possible solution. However, I do not know of any way it can be handled in a reshus harabim (public place) such as a park.

[chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/522415/jewish/How-does-Shabbat-observance-affect-pet-owners.htm) points out

> **Walking a Pet**
>
> Walking a pet on Shabbat is not problematic per se, as long as you
>   avoid carrying the animal or any pet accessories in the "public
>   domain" (See The Shabbat Laws).
>
> While the pet may be collared and leashed, it must be clear that you
>   are walking an animal, not carrying a leash. The pet must therefore
>   remain close to you at all times, and the length of the leash should
>   remain taut; never sagging within a handbreadth of the ground, and no
>   more than a handbreadth of extra leash should dangle from your hand.6
>
> 6 Shulchan Aruch Harav Orach Chaim 305:19. Incidentally, though
>   accessories such as leashes are not a problem, one may not take an
>   animal into a public domain if the animal is bearing a load.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my yard where I need the doggy bags but walking in public out if my property in the street and in a park.

Comment: Many dogs (mine included) like to go while out on their walk - it's part of the value of their "constitutional" for them - and will save up for it.